# recipes.map is not a function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to output the elements in an array as components in reactjs but i'm getting an error 'recipes.map is not a function'
below is my code

```
    fetchRecipes() {
    var recipes = localStorage.getItem('recipes');

    return recipes.map((i) => {
        return <ListItem key={i.recipeName} edit={this.props.edit} delete={this.props.delete} name={i.recipeName}/>
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.fetchRecipes()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and this is recipes

```
 [{"recipeName":"Tomatoes","recipeIngredients":"somtheng, something"}, {"recipeName":"test","recipeIngredients":"somtheng, something"}]
```

Comment: because it is a string...

Comment: are you sure localStorage.getItem is giving you an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localStorage stores strings so you need to convert the string to an array.

```
var recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recipes'));
```

and when you store it, I hope you are using stringify

```
localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes));
```

Answer (score 0):

And with ES2017 it's even easier with `Object.values()`

```
 var json =  [{"recipeName":"Tomatoes","recipeIngredients":"somtheng, something"}, {"recipeName":"test","recipeIngredients":"somtheng, something"}];
 var objects = Object.values(json);
 objects.map((value) => {
     console.log(value.recipeName);
  })
```

Logs:

```
Tomatoes
test
```

Same with ES2015

```
 Object.keys(json).map((i) => console.log((json[i].recipeName)));
```